# Connect php with oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to get data from oracle using php.

But I have a problem happen when connect php with oracle

my code is:

```
<?php/>
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("sys as sysdba", "orcl", "//desktop-jhc9gq7:1158/orcl1");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

But I have a problem :  `ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure`

What is the problem here?

plz help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Go to your sql net ora file and change TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT to 16

Comment: where is this file?

Comment: default:  ORACLE HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN

Comment: sqlnet.ora file contains only two row SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

Comment: ok, add the line then TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16